# Jest - Angular 9 - Class constructor SomeComponentClass cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: angular, jestjs, ts-jest, babel-jest, ts-node

I am migrating our karma test to Jest in an old angular 9 application, and am facing an issue with a couple of tests failing with the following type of exception:

> TypeError: Class constructor SomeComponentClass cannot be invoked
> without 'new'

I followed the Jest setup guides and have referred to some other independent guides and my setup is as follows:

**jest.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    preset: "jest-preset-angular",
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts'],
    globals: {
      'ts-jest': {
        tsconfig: '<rootDir>/src/tsconfig.spec.json',
        stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$',
      },
    },
    coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
    coverageReporters: ["html", "text-summary", "json-summary", "cobertura"],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$': 'jest-preset-angular',
    },
    snapshotSerializers: [
      'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',
      'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot',
      'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment',
    ],
    testEnvironment: "jsdom",
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        "node_modules/(?!@o3|@al|ui-metadata)"
    ],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: [
        "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
        "<rootDir>/dist/",
        "<rootDir>/cypress/",
        "<rootDir>/src/test.ts/"
    ],
    reporters: [ "default" ],
    testMatch: [
        "<rootDir>/src/exposures/**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
  };
```

**test-setup.ts**

```js
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
import '@angular/localize/init';
Object.defineProperty(window, 'CSS', { value: null });
Object.defineProperty(document, 'doctype', {
  value: '<!DOCTYPE html>',
});
Object.defineProperty(window, 'getComputedStyle', {
  value: () => {
    return {
      display: 'none',
      appearance: ['-webkit-appearance'],
    };
  },
});
/**
 * ISSUE: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7101
 * Workaround for JSDOM missing transform property
 */
Object.defineProperty(document.body.style, 'transform', {
  value: () => {
    return {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    };
  },
});
```

**tsconfig.spec.js** (located in src folder)

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": ["jest", "node"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es2015"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

**tsconfig.json** (located in src folder)

```json
{
  "$schema":         "http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "extends":         "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@o3/exposures": [
        "./exposures"
      ],
      "ui-metadata/*": [
        "./../node_modules/ui-metadata"
      ]
    },
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./**/*.d.ts",
    "../node_modules/@o3/**/*.ts",
    "../node_modules/ui-metadata/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "common.testing.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "../node_modules/@o3/core/e2e/*",
    "../node_modules/@o3/design/e2e/*",
    "../node_modules/@al/ng-navigation-components/e2e",
    "../node_modules/@o3/core/testing",
    "../node_modules/@o3/core/src/test.ts",
    "../node_modules/@o3/auth/src/test.ts",
    "../node_modules/@o3/design/src/test.ts",
    "../node_modules/@o3/auth/src/test.ts",
    "../node_modules/@al/ng-navigation-components/src/test.ts",
    "../node_modules/@o3/core/src/typings.d.ts",
    "../node_modules/ui-metadata/test/**/*.ts",
    "../node_modules/@o3/**/*.spec.ts",
    "../node_modules/@o3/dev-tools/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json** (in root of project)

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2015"
  }
}
```

**babel.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    presets: [
      [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          targets: {
            node: 'current'
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  };
```

I also tried this in my babel config:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
       ["@babel/preset-env", { "targets": "defaults" }]
    ]
  };
```

I can't figure out how to get past this issue, it sounds like from what I have read in various places it's down to `babel\tsconfig` setup and how it transpiles `es2015` classes (I think) but I just can't work it out.

Can some offer any clues as to what I may need to do to get past this type of error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.app.json`, change your `target` from `es2015` to `es5`.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```

It will fix the error.

Comment: Yeah that's correct. I ran to this months ago. 'es6' is more safe.

Comment: wasn't it useful? @mindparse

Comment: I tried changing to es6 but it made no difference, still getting the same errors

Comment: did you restart your IDE run `ngcc` and rebuild the project?

Comment: and use `es5` this time. @mindparse

Comment: tried es5, and es6, restarting my IDE (vscode) and re-running ngcc. still getting the same errors.

Comment: do it in `tsconfig.app.json` too and just use `es5`. I had a search and I find out `es6` is not always working. I edited the answer. @mindparse

Answer (score 1):

I also had same issue on my snapshot testing and changing target to es6 didn't work. I found a workaround and overridden the class.

[image]